# How to change duration of executed SpriteKit action

Tags: ios7, sprite-kit

I am executing the following SpriteKit action:

```
    SKAction *moveLeft = [SKAction  moveByX:-moveX y:0 duration:moveDuration];
    SKAction *moveRight = [moveLeft reversedAction];
    SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[moveLeft, moveRight]];

    [my_node runAction [SKAction repeatActionForever:sequence]];
```

I want to slow down the action for few seconds (this happens as a result of a user tap), and after that return to the normal speed. I have tried to do so by using

```
    [my_node runAction [SKAction speedTo: 0.5 duration: 10]];
```

But it didn't work (the node halts for this duration instead of slowing down). Since the object is moving forever, I am not able to remove the action and replace with another one (since it is in the middle of its path) .

Any ideas how to execute this properly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sequence an ivar or property. Then at any time you can do this to slow it down:

```
sequence.speed = 0.5;
```

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer doesn't work for me. My solution is to stop current animation and run it again with needed speed:

```
    removeAllActions()
    sequence.speed = 100 // run 100 times faster
    run(anim)
```