# SpriteKit - change animation speed dynamically

Tags: swift, animation, sprite-kit, skaction

I am new to the SpriteKit framework and cannot figure out how to do the following:

In the middle of the scene I have a sprite to which I apply an .animateWithTextures SKAction. Now I simply want to increase the speed of that animation, or decrease its duration for the same effect.

I made the SKAction a property of my GameScene class so I can access its properties from everywhere, but neither changing its speed nor its duration affects the animation.

I read several threads, the closest to my problem being this one:

[How to change duration of executed SpriteKit action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23314691/how-to-change-duration-of-executed-spritekit-action)

which is from seven years ago, and none of the answers is working for me.

Here is basically what I do:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

   var thePlayer: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode()
   var playerAnimation: SKAction?   
   ...
   ...

   func setInitialAnimation() {
   
      let walkAnimation = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction(named: "PlayerWalk", duration: 1)!)
      self.playerAnimation = walkAnimation
      self.thePlayer.run(walkAnimation)
   }

   func changeAnimationDuration(to duration: CGFloat) {

      self.playerAnimation?.duration = duration
   }
}
```

The animation starts when the setInitialAnimation method is called, but changing the action's duration has no effect. The only thing that works so far is removing the old action from the player sprite and running a new one.

Should it not be possible to change the properties of a running SKAction or is that some kind of fire and forget mechanism?

Comment: Change the node's `speed`?  IIRC that affects currently-running actions.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sknode/1483036-speed

Answer (score 0):

Play around with the timePerFrame to get the correct animation speed.

```
var frames = [SKTexture]()
                        
 for i in 1...10 {
     frames.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: "YourTextureAnimationFrame\(i)"))
 }
                       
 let animate = SKAction.animate(with: frames, timePerFrame: 0.025) 
 //timePerFrame setting the speed of the animation.

 node.run(animate)
```